# Spring bean transformation jaxb

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, javabeans

is it possible to make an @Bean in a Spring configuration class that uses data which is transmitted by a request. Say I get 50 objects in JSON with a restcontroller request (objects from the same app) , and I need the data of said objects and use said data to construct objects for XML-conversion using JAXB. Is it possible to construct beans using this data and then transforming said beans using JAXB?